# Android fragment layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

In my android application I'm replacing Sherlock fragment from another Sherlock fragment. (lets say A from B) I used following code for this replacement

```
   FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   Fragment fragment = new AddNewRaveFragment();
   ft.replace(R.id.raves_frame, fragment,"NewFragmentTag");
   ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
   ft.addToBackStack(null);
   ft.commit();
```

lay out that I use for the fragment A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/raves_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="114dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp" >
</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

but when I'm running the program it shows the lay out shifted to the left like this
[image]

This is the code that I used for the lay out B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

So how can I make it correctly show the lay out in screen ?
Thanks

Comment: Remove `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` line in your layout

Comment: it is because u've give the android:layout_marginLeft and android:layout_marginTop to ur FrameLayout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you have left margin in your `FrameLayout`. Just remove this line `android:layout_marginLeft="114dp"` also remove margin top `android:layout_marginTop="69dp"` this leaving the extra space.

Comment: Yes that solved the problem, thank you very much for the answer, and just another problem, when I add a button to the lay out A even though I replace it by layout B, button comes on top of the edit text of the layout B. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you post your code of replacing the layout B ? I guess the issue may be because of the layout A still resides there. You may not be clearing the fragment.

Comment: Gald to help you .. :)